# SQL : Can’t grab values in descending order when using group by

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

im joining and retrieving values from two tables using the below query. It displays the values in descending order.

```
Leads
63697       Ben
63698       Ben
63699       Ben
63700       Ben
63701       Ben


log

2   63697       Ben         10%     Qualifying
3   63697       Ben         20%     Qualifying
4   63697       Ben         30%     Qualifying
6   63698       Ben         30%     Qualifying
8   63698       Ben     80%     Quoted
10  63698       Ben         70%     Quoted
```

I want to display,

```
63697       Ben         30%     Qualifying
63698       Ben         70%     Quoted
63699       Ben
63700       Ben
63701       Ben
```

The problem is that when I use the query,

```
SELECT leads.id,leads.name, log.prob, log.current_stage FROM leads LEFT JOIN log ON log.leadid = leads.id WHERE leads.name = '$name' ORDER BY log.id DESC
```

It displays all the details for the log table in descending order. But when I try to group them,

```
SELECT leads.id,leads.name, log.prob, log.current_stage FROM leads LEFT JOIN log ON log.leadid = leads.id WHERE leads.name = '$name' GROUP BY log.leadid ORDER BY log.id DESC
```

It grabs the values in the ascending order from the logs table

```
63697       Ben         10%     Qualifying
63698       Ben         30%     Qualifying
63699       Ben
63700       Ben
63701       Ben
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT leads.id,leads.name, log.prob, log.current_stage, log.id AS logid FROM leads LEFT JOIN log ON log.leadid = leads.id WHERE leads.name = '$name' GROUP BY log.leadid
) ORDER BY logid DESC
```

Have seen this quite often, just wrap it in a superquery as shown.

Comment: Thanks alot.... but i had to move the group by outside the wrap and order by inside the subquery to get it working... :)

Answer (score 0):

You are ordering by log.id, which is not a field of your select. You cannot do this as the ORDER BY is evaluated after the SELECT directive.

Change ORDER BY log.id for ORDER BY leads.id, which is the only identifier I see in your SELECT directive.